# Xubuntu Monitor issue

Tags: xubuntu, display, monitor, settings

I did a presentation with my laptop with an external monitor (using latest Xubuntu). After the end of the presentation my laptop ran out of battery. When I got home an logged in again, I had only a desktop picture and no desktop, and figured the system is still set to display the desktop on an external monitor....

I'm travelling around at the moment and don't really have access to another external monitor to fix the problem, and need some of the files in my account.

Are there any keyboard short cuts or anything that could potentially help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Luke

Answer (score 0):

Light DM is is the process that handles the display. You could try and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr/SysReq</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for resetting the display in Ubuntu. I hope this works in Xubuntu too.

The [instructions on how to restart the Xserver](http://www.sudo-juice.com/restart-x-shortcut-for-ubuntu/) may help you.

Comment: If it's set up, you can also use Ctrl+Alt+Backspace

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, Unfortunately no success = (

Comment: I think  you have hibernated or put your laptop in sleep mode. Just try to shut it down completely and restart it.